# is gentile used to signify people of indigenous origin?

Tags: meaning

While "gentile" is used to describe people of non-Jewish or pagan origin, can it be used as a synonym for "indigenous" (with regards to connotation?)

Comment: No <..filler..>

Comment: @TheMathemagician All killer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gentile (n.) 
late 14c., "chivalrous person; member of the nobility;" see gentile (adj.). Also used during 14c. to mean both "one who is not a Christian" and "one who is not a Jew." The Latin word was used in Vulgate to translate Greek ethnikos, from ta ethne "the nations," which translated Hebrew ha goyim "the (non-Jewish) nations."

gentile (adj.) 
mid-13c., "noble, kind, gracious" (mid-12c. as a surname); late 14c., "of noble rank or birth, belonging to the gentry," from Late Latin gentilis "foreign, heathen, pagan," from Latin gentilis "person belonging to the same family, fellow countryman," from gentilis (adj.) "of the same family or clan," from gens (genitive gentis) "race, clan" (see gentle).

Source: Online Etymology Dictionary

The etymology of the word " gentile" support this view.

Gentile: 
1. (Grammar) denoting an adjective or proper noun used to designate a place or the inhabitants of a place, as Spanish and Spaniard
2. (Anthropology & Ethnology) of or relating to a tribe or people

Source: Collins English Dictionary

Comment: it may not be necessary among the English nobility but gratitude unexpressed is vain and subliminally regressive to soul energy and civilizatory progression. So thank you, thank you very much! :)